# How to set the linenumber of an IMarker for a ICompilationUnit?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt, markers

I want to create a marker with a message and colored code line (like EclEmma does) at a given linenumber. I have a `ICompilationUnit` and its resource to create the marker like this:

```
IMarker marker = resource.createMarker("org.epitest.mutationmarker");
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.MESSAGE, "statusDescription");
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER, 5);
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_START, 10);
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_END, 20);
```

Unfortunatly the line number is ignored and the marker is placed at the first line.

[image: The Marker is at the first line not as expected on line 5]

What went wrong? How can i solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CHAR_START` and `CHAR_END` are offsets from the start of the document and are being used in preference to `LINE_NUMBER`. The position display code only uses the line number if neither of the char start and end attributes is specified.

You can use `IDocument.getLineOffset(line)` to get a line offset if you have the `IDocument`.

If you are using a text editor you can get the `IDocument` from that, otherwise you can construct an instance of the `Document` class.

Note: Line numbers in `IDocument` are 0 based, line numbers in `IMarker` are 1 based.

Comment: Do i have to calculate the offset by counting the line breaks or is there a method i can use?

Comment: If you have the `IDocument` you can call `getLineOffset(line)` (Note: lines in `IDocument` start at 0, lines in markers start at 1).

Comment: `new Document(compilationUnit.getSource()).getLineOffset(lineNumber-1)` does the trick. Can you add this to your answer, it may be useful for others. Good work, thx!